# How to prove $\cos 36^{\circ} = (1+ \sqrt 5)/4$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $4 \cos^2 x -2\cos x -1 = 0$.

Use this to show that $\cos 36^{\circ} = (1+ \sqrt 5)/4$, $\cos 72^{\circ} = (-1+\sqrt 5)/4$

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Hmm... so it appears that $(2\cos x-1)^2=\tfrac 54$ from the first statement.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the [Quadratic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula):

The solution to $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

---

The equation is based on the fact that
$$
\cos(5x)=16\cos^5(x)-20\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x)
$$
and that $\cos(5\cdot36^\circ)=-1$ to get
$$
16\cos^5(36^\circ)-20\cos^3(36^\circ)+5\cos(36^\circ)+1=0
$$
Factoring yields
$$
(\cos(36^\circ)+1)(4\cos^2(36^\circ)-2\cos(36^\circ)-1)^2=0
$$
We know that $\cos(36^\circ)+1\ne0$; therefore,
$$
4\cos^2(36^\circ)-2\cos(36^\circ)-1=0
$$
Deciding between the two roots of this equation is a matter of looking at the signs of the roots.

For $\cos(72^\circ)$, use the identity $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$.

Comment: Applying quad formula I do get (1+5√)/4, but how does the 36 degrees come in?

Comment: Use the inverse cosine function arccos....  $x=\arccos{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}}$.....

Comment: OH, I got it alr. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst That looks like a circular argument to me. (_Why_ is $36^\circ = \arccos\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}$?) Also, if you had access to $\arccos$ all along, why bother with the quadratic equation?

Comment: @Teddy: I hope the last addition to my answer makes things look less circular (although $\cos$ is a circular function).

Comment: how is it circular? you substitute $y=\cos{x}$  You solve the quadratic and get $\cos{x}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$.  Then you solve for $x$...how is that circular?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst: First of all, it was a play on words since Teddy mentioned a circular argument and $\cos$ is a circular function. However, I think he was wondering why $36^\circ$ satisfied $4\cos^2(x)-2\cos(x)-1=0$ since that was never explained.

Comment: So I missed the joke.... Darn....  I try not to be that guy...  :)

Answer (score 4):

To derive this from fundamentals, note that

$$\sin{108^{\circ}} = \sin{72^{\circ}}$$

then use a double-angle and triple-angle forumla:

$$\sin{2 x} = 2 \sin{x} \cos{x}$$
$$\sin{3 x} = 3 \sin{x} - 4 \sin^3{x}$$

In this case, $x=36^{\circ}$.  Setting the above two equations equal to each other results in the quadratic equation in question:

$$2 \cos{x} = 3 - 4 (1-\cos^2{x}) = 4 \cos^2{x}-1$$

The rest follows from the above discussion.

Comment: I believe that only this answer is right. To make the first answer valid, you need to make also reasoning that cos is a function on $[0;Pi]$.
The solution suggested by Ron is quite universal, as I think it should work for any k, not only for 5 (36 = $Pi/5$).

Answer (score 0):

Using $\cos5\theta = 16\cos^5 \theta - 20 \cos^3 \theta + 5 \cos \theta$;

$\cos 180 = 16\cos^5 36 - 20 \cos^3 36 + 5 \cos 36$

Let $\cos36 = x$:

$-1 = 16x^5 -20x^3 +5x$

[Its solutions are](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3D+16x%5E5+-20x%5E3+%2B5x+%2B1) ${-1,\frac{1- \sqrt{5}}{4}},\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{4}$

And as $\cos36 = x$, $\cos 36$ must be equal to one of them.

$\cos 36$ must be equal to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$, as $-1$ and $\frac{1- \sqrt{5}}{4}$ are negative.