# Find the value of $4\sin 36^\circ \cos 18^\circ$ without using their surd values

Tags: trigonometry

Without using the surd value for $\sin 36^\circ$ or $\cos 18^\circ$, prove that
$$ 4 \sin 36^\circ \cos 18^\circ = \sqrt{5} $$

**My attempt:**

$ 4\sin36^\circ \cos18^\circ \!\cdot\!\dfrac{\sin18^\circ}{\sin18^\circ}=$

$=\dfrac{2\sin^2 36^\circ}{\sin18^\circ}=$

$=\dfrac{1-\cos72^\circ}{\sin18^\circ}=$

$=\dfrac{1-\sin18^\circ}{\sin18^\circ}=$

$=\dfrac{1}{\sin18^\circ}-1\,.$

Comment: And what have you tired? You're expected to show your attempt here.

Comment: i simplified the equation to 1/sin18 - 1

Comment: It would be useful if you show how you got to your answer; i.e. the steps in your working

Comment: and now i have to put the values of sin 18

Comment: Possible hint: try to expand $\sin 5x$ or $\cos 5x$ as a polynomial in $\sin x$ or $\cos x$, and use something about the zeros of that polynomial.

Comment: I would try this post here for guidance...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524482/proving-the-closed-form-of-sin48-circ (there are methods for finding $\sin 18°$ in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it results that

$\begin{align}4\cos^2\!18\unicode{176}&=\dfrac{4\cos^3\!18\unicode{176}-3\cos18\unicode{176}}{\cos18\unicode{176}}+3=\dfrac{\cos54\unicode{176}}{\cos18\unicode{176}}+3=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{\sin36\unicode{176}}{\cos18\unicode{176}}+3=\dfrac{2\sin18\unicode{176}\cos18\unicode{176}}{\cos18\unicode{176}}+3=\\[3pt]&=2\sin18\unicode{176}+3\;\;,\quad\color{blue}{(1)}\end{align}$

$4\sin^2\!18\unicode{176}=1-2\sin18\unicode{176}\,.\;\;\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

Moreover ,

$\begin{align}4\sin36\unicode{176}\cos18\unicode{176}&=8\sin18\unicode{176}\cos^2\!18\unicode{176}=\\[3pt]&\overset{\color{brown}{(1)}}{=}2\sin18\unicode{176}\big(2\sin18\unicode{176}\!+3\big)=\\[3pt]&=4\sin^2\!18\unicode{176}\!+6\sin18\unicode{176}\overset{\color{brown}{(2)}}{=}4\sin18\unicode{176}+1=\\[3pt]&=\sqrt{\big(4\sin18\unicode{176}\!+1\big)^{\!2}}=\\[3pt]&=\sqrt{16\sin^2\!18\unicode{176}+8\sin18\unicode{176}+1}=\\[3pt]&\overset{\color{brown}{(2)}}{=}\sqrt{4-8\sin18\unicode{176}+8\sin18\unicode{176}+1}=\\[3pt]&=\sqrt5\;.\end{align}$

Comment: loved your solution thank you

Comment: @shivjindal, you are welcome !