# Find $\sin{\frac{\pi}{10}}$ in form of $a+b\sqrt{k}$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots, quartics

Use De Moivre's Theorem to express $\cos{5\theta}, \sin{5\theta}$ in powers of $\sin{\theta}$ and $\cos{\theta}$.

Show that $$\frac{\cos{5\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}=16\sin^4{\theta}-12\sin^2{\theta}+1$$

Find the solutions of $$16\sin^4{\theta}-12\sin^2{\theta}+1=0,\ for\ 0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Use this result to find $\sin{\frac{\pi}{10}}$ in the form $a+b\sqrt{k}$, and give the values of $a,\ b\ and\ k$.

For $\cos{5\theta}$, I have $\cos5{\theta}=\cos^5{\theta}-10\cos^2{\theta}\sin^3{\theta}+5\cos{\theta}\sin^4{\theta}$

and for $\sin{5\theta}$, I have $\sin{5\theta}=5\cos^4{\theta}\sin{\theta}-10\cos^2{\theta}\sin^3{\theta}+\sin^5{\theta}$

Then it's easy to get $\frac{\cos{5\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}=16\sin^4{\theta}-12\sin^2{\theta}+1$.

So on, $\frac{\cos{5\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}=16\sin^4{\theta}-12\sin^2{\theta}+1=0$

Since $\cos{\theta}\ne0$, so $\cos{5\theta}=0$

Then $$5\theta=\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\frac{7\pi}{2},\frac{9\pi}{2},$$

$$\therefore \theta=\frac{\pi}{10},\frac{3\pi}{10},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{7\pi}{10},\frac{9\pi}{10}$$

Since $\cos{\theta}\ne0, \therefore \theta\ne\frac{\pi}{2}, and\ also\ 0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{10}, \frac{3\pi}{10}$$

Then I used the quadratic formula to get $$\sin^2\frac{\pi}{10}=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{8}$$

But this is wrong somehow. Can anyone give me some hints to finish this question?

Comment: they asked for $\sin \frac{\pi}{10}  $ rather than $\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{10}  .$  Since you will need it, what is $(\sqrt 5 \pm 1)^2$

Comment: As another fairly different-looking approach: $\sin(\pi/10) = \cos(2 \pi/5)$, and for $\theta := 2\pi/5$ we have $\cos(3\theta) = \cos(2\theta)$.  Therefore, if $x = \sin(\pi/10)$ then $4x^3 - 3x = 2x^2 - 1$ and also $x \ne 1$ from which you can get a quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: I give three different methods for finding square root expressions of $\sin \frac{\pi}{10}$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{10}$ in my answer to [Proving the closed form of $\sin48^\circ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1524772/13130).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a correct expression, but it's not what the question asked for.  $$\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{10} = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{8} \tag{1}$$
is correct (we discard the other root $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{8}$ because it is greater than $\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$).  But the question asked for $\sin \frac{\pi}{10}$ in the form $a + b \sqrt{k}$.

To this end, note that $$3-\sqrt{5} = \frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{(\sqrt{5})^2 - 2\sqrt{5} + 1}{2} = \frac{(\sqrt{5} - 1)^2}{2}. \tag{2}$$  Hence
$$\sin \frac{\pi}{10} = \sqrt{\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{8}} = \sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)^2}{16}} = \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{4}. \tag{3}$$  This yields $a = -1/4$, $b = 1/4$, $k = 5$.

Answer (score 1):

For another approach to solve for $x := \sin(\pi/10)$ in $16 x^4 - 12 x^2 + 1 = 0$, let us try completing the square in a slightly unusual way: instead of using the first two terms, we will use the outer two terms and observe that $(4x^2 - 1)^2 = 16x^4 - 8x^2 + 1$.  Therefore,
$$16x^4 - 12x^2 + 1 = (4x^2 - 1)^2 - 4x^2 = (4x^2 - 2x - 1) (4x^2 + 2x - 1).$$
From here, it should be easy to find the roots of the polynomial, and then you just need to determine which one of those roots is actually equal to $\sin(\pi/10)$.

Answer (score 1):

OP’s answer is correct! It can be completed by just taken square root by letting
$$
\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{8}=(a+b \sqrt{5})^2=a^2+5b^2+2ab\sqrt 5
$$
By comparing the rational and irrational parts on both sides, we have
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a^2+5 b^2=\frac{3}{8} \cdots(1)\\
2 a b=-\frac{1}{8} \cdots(2)
\end{array}\right.
$$
$(1)+(2)\times 3$ gives
$$
a^2+5 b^2=-6 a b \Leftrightarrow  a=-b \text { or }-5 b \textrm{ (rejected after checking)}
$$
Putting back to $(2)$ gives $a=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $b=\frac{1}{4}$ and hence
$$
\boxed{\sin \frac{\pi}{10}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}
$$

**Alternative method**

Let $\theta=\frac{\pi}{10}  $, then $$
\begin{aligned}
& \cos 2 \theta=\sin 3 \theta \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & 1-2 \sin ^2 \theta=3 \sin \theta-4 \sin ^3 \theta \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & 4 x^3-2 x^2-3 x+1=0 \cdots (*), \quad \textrm{ where }x=\sin \theta. 
\end{aligned}
$$
Noting that $x=1$ is a root of $(*)$, we can factorise it as
$$
(x-1)\left(4 x^2+2 x-1\right)=0 
\Leftrightarrow x=1 \text { or } \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}
$$
Since $\sin \frac{\pi}{10}$ is positive other than $1$, we have
$$
\boxed{\sin \frac{\pi}{10}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For diversity, here is a geometrical argument,
which should be accesible to a lower level. Consider the isosceles triangle $\Delta ABC$ with side $BC=1$, $AB=AC=x$, and an angle of $36^\circ$ in $A$.
The angle bisector in $B$ intersects $AC$ in $D$.

[image: computing sin 18 with geometric means]

Then shown angles put in evidence the isosceles triangles $\Delta DAB$
and $\Delta BCD$. This gives $AD=BD=BC=1$. On the other side, the side $AC=x$ is cut in $D$ in two segments that respect the proportion $AD:DC=BA:BC=x:1$, which leads to $AD=x\cdot x/(1+x)$, $CD=x\cdot 1/(1+x)$. We obtain an equation for $x$,
$$1=AD=\frac {x^2}{1+x}\ ,$$
with the positive solution $x=\frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)$. Draw now the angle bisector from $A$, for each of the formed angles of $18^\circ$ we have then
in each of the formed right triangles with hypotenuse $x=AB=AC$:
$$
\sin \frac\pi{10} =\sin 18^\circ = \frac{1/2}x=\frac{1/2}{(\sqrt5+1)/2}
=\frac 1{\sqrt 5+1}
=\frac {\sqrt 5-1}{5-1}=
\bbox[yellow]{\ \frac 14(\sqrt 5-1)\ }\ .
$$